# Getting statistics on bitcoin >transactions< - breakdown by size

Tags: charts, statistics

Now that bitcoin is going more mainstream, particularly with the futures listings and so on,

https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=%40XBT.1&tab=news

it's quite easy to get statistics on **price performance** for bitcoin.

However what I want to see is this - quite simply, stats on bitcoin "spends" and that trend over the last weeks, months.

So, ideally you'd really want this broken down as a histogram.

Imagine yourself trying to sell investors on bitcoin: what they want to know is transaction flow:

- **how many** transactions in the last 24 hrs
- a **graph** of that for a few months
- **breakdown** by size .. under a buck's worth, 1-10, over 10

This straightforward information is in my experience the **first thing investors look for**, when I try to pitch old money on investing in one Bitcoin scheme or another.

How do I get this information? Maybe I'm missing something obvious - it seems to be the first sort of site one would set up to promote bitcoin.

How many transactions in the last 24 hrs ?

Comment: What do you mean by "spends"?  If you simply mean # of transactions, there are plenty of places to get these stats, and it's not even too difficult to calculate them on your own with a full node.  If you mean "spending on goods or services" rather than trading...well that's much more difficult to determine.

Comment: hi @Jestin "there are plenty of places to get these stats" it's probably one of those things that's easy for you as a highly expert insider.  I want a simple website "bitcoinstats.com".  And many "ordinary" investors want that.  Based on your expert insider knowledge, where is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Donely that https://blockchain.info/charts is probably what you are looking for.

Here are some other sites that I refer to for blockchain stats.

- https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/historical - Gives you historical transaction volume
- https://blockchair.com/ - A block explorer that let's you query more details. You could probably create a historical transactions graph from their data.
- http://statoshi.info/dashboard/db/transactions - More technical stats.
- https://coin.dance/stats - I don't see a transaction graph here but it's a good site with various statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah what your saying makes a lot of sense. Blockchain info [graphs](https://blockchain.info/charts) offers allot of charts to show the data that you are referring to. Do you want something in more detail, if so there are probably some api's around that you can use to your hearts desire.

Comment: Fantastic information. It seems to be running at about 200,000 transactions a day, https://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions?timespan=1year ........ BUT .............. I can see no information on breaking that down.  how do we histogram that sucker?